# Problems registering custom check-in policy

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, tfs

I've created a custom check-in policy in Visual Studio 2010 (in C# with .Net 3.5). I've followed the guide here to create this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668980.aspx

I've added a new registry key as listed in Step 2 but my check-in policy does not appear in the list for me to select (as instructed by step 3.3).

I have triple checked the following aspects:

1. The registry string key is named the same as my DLL without the DLL extension.
2. The registry key value points to the full path to the Debug assembly including the full file name with extension (I've also tried using the Release version too).

Can anyone suggest why this is not showing up?

Comment: Does this policy need to be registered and working for TFS2008 or TFS2010?

Comment: Please don't put things like "Team Foundation Server: " in your titles. On [so], we use tags to organize questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to find the issue. I was missing the [Serializable] attribute on the main class that inherits from `PolicyBase`. And this wasn't causing any errors.

Comment: Another common Gotcha is that this "main class" that inherits from PolicyBase must be Public (not private, protected, or internal), otherwise it will not show up in the list to select.